# sql parser error: Expected identifier, found: \u001b"

Tags: database, cnosdb

I can't execute the following sql in CnosDB, I can't find what's wrong, Can anyone help me?

```
usage_schema ❯ select sample(value, 3), time from coord_data_in gropup by time;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected identifier, found: \u001b"}
usage_schema ❯ select sample(value, 3), time from coord_data_in group by time;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected identifier, found: \u001b"}
usage_schema ❯ select sample(value, 3), time from coord_data_in group by time;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010009","error_message":"sql parser error: Expected identifier, found: \u001b"}
usage_schema ❯
```

Comment: `\u001b` is an invisible control character. If you copy/pasted this code from somewhere else, that's probably the issue. I'm fairly certain that if you manually type those statements in you wouldn't get the error. i.e. try copy pasting this in: `select sample(value,3), time from coord_data_in group by time;`